# Promise.all() with map, silenced

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

actually I'm facing a problem with Promises, a miss understanding surely.

I have an array with a list of ids that I use to make an API call that I'm sure it's valid and working. So I have to make foreach element in this list an API call => Promise.

I read about promises and I find this clean way to make it :

```
clean(){
/** Here, I'm just cleaning invalid ids to avoid a silenced map. I tried the 
whole output in the API explorator, and it works well*/
this.facebook.objectIdsToDelete.forEach(element => {
  let index = this.facebook.objectIdsToFilter.indexOf(element);
  this.facebook.objectIdsToFilter.splice(index, 1);
});

Promise.all(this.facebook.objectIdsToFilter.map(value=>{
  return this.facebook.callApiLikes(value);
}))
.then((responses) => {
  this.debogger.debogSomething(responses);
})
.catch((reason) => {
  this.debogger.debogSomething(reason);
})
}
```

debogger => it's a popup to show object content. 
this.facebook.objecIdsToFilter => is a string[]

This popup do not raise, nothing happens. 
Where I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Does `this.facebook.callApiLikes(value)` actually return a promise?

Comment: "what am I doing wrong" - the answer is you are not using a debugger

Comment: @RalphKing, yes, it returns promise

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko I'm developping on Ionic 3 ... Since I'm using cordova, and native components, debogger doesn't work anymore for me. I searched a lot to solve that, didn't find any solution :(